# Does this wire gauze contain asbestos? Can I tell visually?

Tags: safety, equipment

I bought a wire gauze which claimed to be made of ceramic, and asbestos-free. However, I bought it from Amazon (not a trustworthy source), and I see fibers around the edge of the center. Is there a way to tell whether this is asbestos?

[image: wire gauze picture]

Comment: Just wondering why you bought something from an 'untrusted' source that you might worry about the health impacts of. Seems, well, odd.

Comment: @porphyrin Part of my question is whether it's possible to tell visually or by its characteristics. If it's not, that is an answer.

Comment: that was my point, you cannot tell just from the photo what its made from.

Comment: @porphyrin Thank you. Then I'm assuming the fiber at least could be fiberglass. I'm not familiar with how wire gauzes are made.

Comment: This question should be reopened as it does not ask about safety, only identification.  If the OP had asked whether the wire was stainless or not I do not see a reason why the question would have been closed. Though I do acknowledge that there are two questions in this question.

Comment: @A.K. I'll remove the 2nd question and keep it just about identification.

Comment: Probabilities are high that it is 316 SS. It is often used for small stuff like this.

Comment: Unless the component is made to be used with a gas burner, in which case it is likely an Inconel.